# According to which meta ethical theories are only some things permissible and everyone is right about what is permitted?

Tags: metaethics

Can someone give a run down of the popular ways of thinking about ethics and which meta-ethical theories claim that *only some things are permitted*? I've read a couple of SEP articles on ethics, nothing much more, and so my question is a bit limited, but I'm not directly asking about 'truth' or "objectivity", only which philosophers out there would agree.

In light of any answer, philosophers which say only some things are permitted, I'm wondering which of them say that *everyone is right* about what is permitted, which meta-ethical theory allows for both.

I'm guessing some species of relativism might allow them both, but I'm not sure.

Comment: i googled moral error theory recently and it seems a bit like that in practice, but i don't really understand the practical implications of it, not yet

Comment: The gist of practical implication of moral error theory is perhaps the same as the illusory nature of phenomenal-consciousness as discussed in yesterday's [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103103/the-ultimate-absurdity-if-consciousness-is-an-illusion-how-can-anything-we-kno). Error doesn't mean *arbitrariness* as if there's a meta random generator constantly befalls and confuses us human beings. Even in dreams we see meanings and values at least relatively and comparatively...

Comment: well there's "arbitrary" and "anything goes" and i'm not sure those are exactly the same @DoubleKnot "whatever i think it is" need not be arbitrary, in that what i think is conditioned by habit etc

Comment: I believe colloquially they are proper names for the same property...

Comment: ok that may be the case. yeah i agree error doesn't mean "anything goes", but afaik it does allow it @DoubleKnot and that has practical implications

Comment: i don't even mention moral error in my question @DoubleKnot so i am not sure what i'm meant to have misunderstood.

Comment: You have many posts, I believe actually it's this [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102797/which-philosophers-have-defended-both-the-claim-that-any-attitude-can-ground-mea) about moral error theory...

Comment: I didn't say you misunderstood anything, just based on your today's enlightenment on the other QM PSR post about random arbitrariness (anything goes) to possibly connect to moral error theory...

Comment: oh i see @DoubleKnot well, thanks for the concern